# error : "cannot be converted to 1 dimensional array"?

Tags: vb.net

Hopefully this is one of those simple ones that MSDN doesn't cover but you guys will know : I have a pre existing project with a bunch of buttons in it. I've created a new custom button control that adds some extra functionality. but when I try to make my buttons to be of the new class, only the FIRST one works. any additional ones cause an error. This is the part of the code where it fails (from form.designer.vb):

```
Friend WithEvents Button20 As WindowsApplication1.UserControl1()
Friend WithEvents Button19 As WindowsApplication1.UserControl1()

Me.Button20 = New WindowsApplication1.UserControl1()
Me.Button19 = New WindowsApplication1.UserControl1()
```

the first line works. but button19 crashes and I get the following :

***Error    2   Value of type 'WindowsApplication1.UserControl1' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of WindowsApplication1.UserControl1'.***

and so on for all other attempts to make something a usercontrol1. any ideas?

Comment: What is the decleration of Button19? Share more relevant code, also is there something in UserControl1 constructor?

Comment: It seems that `Button19` is declared as an array (or the reverse, but not likely). As Esko said, find the declaration for the button in the Designer code and post it here.

Comment: posted it below. but the code i'm working with is all the stuff that was auto generated by the designer. All i've changed is windows.forms.button to WindowsApplication1.UserControl1. All the other syntax has not been changed from what worked before

Comment: Unfortunately you shouldn't post it as an answer (because it is not an answer). I added the code to your question instead. -- As for your issue try changing every `WindowsApplication1.UserControl1()` to `WindowsApplication1.UserControl1`.

Comment: Hi Vincent. That's the first thing i tried before posting here, had no effect.

Comment: Then I think your only option is to remove every designer generated line of it, and recreate it via the designer interface.